# Internet radio on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, streaming, internet-radio

Has anyone installed an internet radio client on Linux? I am trying to install a couple of them like gst123 and istreamer, but no breakthrough yet.

Answer (score 2):

Rhythmbox has internet radio functionality and is installed by default if you pick the default (GNOME) version of Ubuntu.

Comment: good answer, first try out the already installed tools, then look for other if they do not fit...

Answer (score 0):

What?
Opena  terminal and type the following commands:
To get mplayer, the famous media player: `sudo apt-get install mplayer`
To get a graphical interface for mplayer: 
`sudo apt-get install smplayer`

For restricted stuff support in every player (like mp3. Since you can't play it default):
`sudo apt-get install ubuntu-restricted-extras`

Also, check [Medibuntu](http://www.medibuntu.org/) for codecs, other restricted stuff if your media still won't play.)

(Hope this is what you meant. Next time please clarify your question and use a "cleaner language", don't be so 1337.)

Comment: mplayer is good, but as internet-radio player the features lack...

Comment: What do you mean? It can handle playlists, multiple features.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend you to look for a specialized ubuntu-forum, since there you are helped more on topic than here can ever be (so I think its nice to see more and more ubuntu-questions here...)

As others stated, try out Rhythmbox first, it has good support for internet-radio, can save multiple radio stations and can get more out of iradio with plugins.

I for myself would hint you on banshee as alternative, which is spoken to be the successor of rhythmbox sometime, or quod-libet which is also a fine musik-player.